# Remove all occurrences from list of dict python

Tags: python, list, numpy, dictionary, scipy

I have this code:

```
>>> my_list = [
...     {'key1': 1, 'key2': 1., 'key3': 'a'},
...     {'key1': 0, 'key2': 0., 'key3': 'b'}
... ]
>>>
```

I need to remove all occurrences of a key (i.e 'key2') from my_list:

```
>>> my_list = [
...     {'key1': 1, 'key3': 'a'},
...     {'key1': 0, 'key3': 'b'}
... ]
>>>
```

What is the most pythonic and faster mode to do that?

Additional note: 'my_list' is in fact a list with many more rows, and each dict have dozens of keys.

Comment: What is the difference between the two ``my_list``s? I see none. What is the desired result then?

Comment: Thanks zegkljan is fixed in the description.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for my_dict in my_list:
    my_dict.pop('key2', None)
```

You can also remove keys with `del`, but unless you're certain that it's present in every dictionary, you'd need to explicitly check whether the key is there or not:

```
for my_dict in my_list:
   if 'key2' in my_dict:
       del my_dict['key2']
```

or:

```
for my_dict in my_list:
   try:
       del my_dict['key2']
   except KeyError:
       pass
```

That last piece of code is an example of the "Pythonic" principle that "it's easier to ask forgiveness than permission", meaning that one should handle exceptions in preference to doing work in advance to prevent them occurring. However, it's not a very *good* example of the principle, since in this case it's more code for no obvious benefit in clarity.

Comment: @Francesco: yes, I was just working on that as you commented. As I've explained, it has the advantage of illustrating a general pythonic principle, but I don't think that principle is very compelling for this particular case.

Comment: Ok thanks, but what if I want to remove a list of keys, i.e: `keys_to_remove = ['key2', 'key5']`
The most pythonic way to do that? (not using two for-loops).
Thanks!

Comment: @gsanchez: I don't want to get too hung up on the definition of "pythonic", but in my opinion the best way to write that is with two loops. If instead of modifying existing data structures you were creating new ones, as in jDo's answer, then other ways can be better.

Answer (score 2):

As with most lists and dictionaries and python, `.pop()` is the best way of removing an item from a data object.

To remove a specific key from every dictionary, iterate through the list of dictionaries with a `for` loop and use`.pop()` (with arguments of the key you want to remove and `None` for the return) to remove the key.

```
for dictionary in list_of_dictionaries:
    dictionary.pop(key_you_want_to_pop, None)
```

For more information, see [this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Best of luck, and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

If you like a oneliner you can use `map`

```
map(lambda d: d.pop('key2', None), my_list)
```

Comment: A note on py2/3 differences: in 3 this will do nothing until the map is consumed.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it. E.g. using a list comprehension:

```
my_list = [{'key3': 'a', 'key2': 1.0, 'key1': 1}, {'key3': 'b', 'key2': 0.0, 'key1': 0}]

my_new_list = [{y[0]:y[1] for y in x.items() if y[0] != "key2"} for x in my_list]
```

To remove a list of keys using this approach (creates a new list):

```
my_new_list = [{y[0]:y[1] for y in x.items() if y[0] not in ["key2", "key3"]} for x in my_list]
```

**Note:** The OP accepted this answer; most likely because, at the time of writing, it's the only one that can remove several keys from a list. However, this solution creates new dictionaries and adds them to a new list; it does not modify the original list. This is all well and good if you want to preserve the original list but it's bound to be slower than modifying the list *in place*.  Some rough `timeit` tests on my laptop showed that `pop`ping in a `for` loop was 3 - 3.5 times faster than the solution in this answer.

Always pick the right tool for the job.